# nested use of Apply/Map/MapThread in pure functions

Tags: list-manipulation, map, pure-function

**1. My main question**

I have a function with two argument slots. I wan't to apply this function to 2 lists with different length's. I thought in this solution:

```
Map[Map[f[# &, #], b] &, c]
```

But it doesn't work. Why is that?

**Example**

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]


  b = {1, 2}
  c = {1, 2, 3}
```

The output seems pretty close of what i wanted but not close enough:

```
{{Sin[#1 &][1], Sin[#1 &][2]}, {Sin[2 (#1 &)][1], 
  Sin[2 (#1 &)][2]}, {Sin[3 (#1 &)][1], Sin[3 (#1 &)][2]}}
```

**2.** It seems that i only need to take the &'s out of the square brackets.

**a)** Is it so? Why?

**b)** how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Outer`: `Outer[f,c,b]` for example. Your solution wasn't absolutely wrong the only problem was `f[# &, #]` It should have been: `Map[Function[$x$,Map[f[# , $x$]&, b]], c]`

Comment: If you define `f` like `f[x_][y_]:=Sin[x y]` then this works great `f[#] /@ b & /@ c`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But it doesn't work. Why is that?

It becomes visible when you inspect the inner `Map` only. I replace the slot for the outer function with 1, because we don't need it to see the error

```
b = {1, 2};
c = {1, 2, 3};
Map[f[# &, 1], b]

(* {f[#1 &, 1][1], f[#1 &, 1][2]} *)
```

This is not what you expect and when you look a bit closer, you instantly see that your *function* is not a `Function`

```
f[# &, 1] // FullForm
(* f[Function[Slot[1]],1] *)
```

Therefore, evaluating `f[#&,1][blub]` does **not** result in `f[blub,1]` as you need it. Now you may think, OK, the `&` is at the wrong place, it needs to be left to the closing `]` of `f` like this `f[#,1]&`. Yes, but now you instantly run into trouble when you replace the 1 with your second `#` again, because now, the slot belongs to the inner function, which is not what you want.

The direct solution is fairly simple. Replace one *anonymous* function with an explicit `Function` where you can *name* the argument

```
b = {1, 2};
c = {1, 2, 3};
Map[Function[arg, Map[f[#, arg] &, b]], c]

(* {{f[1, 1], f[2, 1]}, {f[1, 2], f[2, 2]}, {f[1, 3], f[2, 3]}} *)
```

If you have understood your mistake, you may want to think using a more direct approach. The one suggested by Spawn in the comment is really short **and** readable

```
Outer[f, c, b]
```

The function `Outer` is probably not known by new *Mathematica* users. One function which is one of the first you learn is `Table`

```
Table[f[bi, ci], {ci, c}, {bi, b}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of outer. I was trying to do something more general. For instance, imagine that i want to "outer" in a subpart of the arguments of a function and then "thread" on another subpart.Not sure if this happens often, though